# Loop through 3 levels of lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to set a dictionary that will allow me to loop through 3 levels. For example:

Level 1: Meats, Non-Meats
Level 2: Fruit, Vegetable, Pig, Cow
Level 3: Apple, Oranges, Broccoli, Carrots, Bacon, Ham, Ribs, Steak

The dictionary I have attempted is as follows:

```
X = {
"Meats":{
    "Pig":[["Bacon"], ["Ham"]], 
    "Cow":[["Ribs"], ["Steak"]]
    },
"Non-Meats":{
    "Fruit":[["Apple"], ["Oranges"]], 
    "Vegetable":[["Broccoli"], ["Carrots"]]
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to handle this would be appreciated.

Comment: why `"Pig": [["Bacon"], ["Ham"]]` and not `"Pig": ["Bacon", "Ham"]`?

Comment: Post your attempts always please. We wont do your homework completely for you. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is create a nested dictionary.

One thing that may help you understand the structure you're creating is proper formatting. There's a standard for formatting called PEP8, but as long as you're consistent, you can use whatever style you want.

```
X = {
    "Meats": {
        "Pig": [
            ["Bacon"], ["Ham"]
        ],

        "Cow": [
            ["Ribs"], ["Steak"]
        ]
     },

     "Non-Meats": {
         "Fruit": [
            ["Apple"],  ["Oranges"]
        ],

        "Vegetable": [
            ["Broccoli"], ["Carrots"]
        ]
    }
}
```

Does this formatting make the structure easier to read? It seems to me that the brackets around each inner item are unnecessary, as they're already inside part of a list

If we rewrite the Vegetable item of the 'non-meats' dictionary item without those inner square brackets, it looks like this:

```
"Vegetable": [
    "Broccoli", "Carrots"
]
```

Then you could get a list of the vegatables like so:

```
veggies = x['Non-Meats']['Vegetable']
```

The variable 'veggies' is now an iterable list. Printing that list would result in something like this:

```
['Broccoli', 'Carrots']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to solve such a problem is work step by step through your dictionary and figure out what exactly you need to iterate through.

**Step one:**
How will you iterate through the top-level dictionary keys?

```
for key in X:
    do something
```

**Step two:**

*Q*: For each key, what do you have to iterate through?

*Answer*: another dict. So, we have including the previous step:

```
for key in X:
    for key_two in X[key]:
        do something
```

**Step 3:**

*Q*: What do you finally have within each of these dicts?

*Answer*: list of lists (e.g. `[["Bacon"]]`). I'm not sure why each of these is a list, you could just make them strings. For example, `{"Pig": ["Bacon", "Ham"]}`. However, for what you have, we get:

```
for key in X:
    for key_two in X[key]:
        for food in X[key][key_two]:
            print food # If you want to print without the list, it'd be either a final nested loop or "print food[0]"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is perfect.  The list of lists was an accident.

Comment: There is no connection between the answer and the question. Yet it is accepted and upvoted.

Comment: The question has been edited, the original question was asking how to loop through the dictionary and not how to design such a dictionary. My answer was tailored to that version of the question.